# How do I install a specific version of numpy with pip?

Tags: python, numpy

Recently for various reasons I have been uninstalling and reinstalling all my python packages. Two of these packages are numpy and tensorflow. After attempting to reinstall numpy after tensorflow, I got the message that tensorflow required

> ERROR: tensorflow 2.3.1 has requirement numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0, but you'll have numpy 1.19.4 which is incompatible.

So I was wondering how I could install a specific version of numpy, such as version 1.18.5

Answer (score 15):

```
pip install --force-reinstall numpy==1.18.5
```

Comment: nice I resolved my issue.